# execute code only if all inputs are valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to execute the code (sending ajax form) only if all inputs are valid.

The code I use right now is:

```
jQuery('.btn-save').on("click", function() {
    var submit = true;

    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('error');
        submit = false;
    });

    if (submit) {
        jQuery.ajax({ // ... do the job });
    }
});
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do that, not involving the creation of the `submit` variable.
I tried with `return` inside the each loop, but it returns from the loop, not from the parent onclick event.

Comment: can you provide the HTML code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not need `each` after `find`. `jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid')` will return an array of  jquery object. Check if the length is 0. When 0 it means no `input:invalid`.
then make the ajax call. Else you can directly use `addClass` without iterating the result of `find`

```
jQuery('.btn-save').on("click", function() {
  const errInputs = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid');
  if (errInputs.length === 0) {
    // ajax code here
  } else {
    errInputs.addClass('error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```js
$('.btn-save').on("click", function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('error');
    });

    if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid').length > 0) {
        jQuery.ajax({ // ... do the job });
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about using https://jqueryvalidation.org/ ?

https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

It becomes as simple as specifying attributes on inputs and calling **validate()**:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Promise object of es6

```js
function handle() {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    
        const elements = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input:invalid');

        if (elements) {

            elements.each(()=> {
                jQuery(this).addClass('error');
                submit = false;
                resolve(false)
            });

        } else {
            resolve(true)
        }
    });

    promise.then(valid=>{
        if(valid){
            // jQuery.ajax({ // ... do the job });
        } else {
            // alert('error');
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: it seems more complicated of my solution